# Is there a use as "due xxx(specific date)"?

Tags: grammar

When I did listening today, I heard the sentence "But I have another article **due** the same day". I have checked "due", it only has meanings as adv，adj and noun. I don't know why "due" in the sentence is used in that way that seems to be a verb or preposition.

Comment: It's an adjective. The phrase is a shortened form of *another article [**that is**] due*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Due" is still an adjective there. A sentence like "Another article is due the same day" works the same way as "The same day, another article is due."

Noun phrases referring to times can often be used in a way similar to adverbs or prepositional phrases, and that's what's happening here. Other examples of the same thing are "I'm going to the store next week" and "Last year, we hired many new employees."

Comment: Thank you, these examples make me clear.